# Reopen Android app after some time when minimized using onPause callback

Tags: android, android-activity, automation, start-activity, onpause

I'm developing an Android application and for some reason that has not yet been identified at random times it minimizes itself. I want to use the onPause callback function that is called when the app is minimized to programmatically reopen it.

As already mentioned, being able to make a rule to call the application reopening after a while so that it is not reopened immediately using Timer and TimerTask and a Boolean key:

```
  private Timer mActivityTransitionTimer;
  private TimerTask mActivityTransitionTimerTask;
  public boolean wasInBackground;
  private final long MAX_ACTIVITY_TRANSITION_TIME_MS = 3000;

  @Override
  protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    System.out.println("debug Pause/Resume: --- P A U S E ----");

    startActivityTransitionTimer();
  }

  @Override
  protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    System.out.println("debug Pause/Resume: ---- R E S U M E ---");

    stopActivityTransitionTimer();
  }

  public void stopActivityTransitionTimer() {
    if (this.mActivityTransitionTimerTask != null) {
        this.mActivityTransitionTimerTask.cancel();
    }

    if (this.mActivityTransitionTimer != null) {
        this.mActivityTransitionTimer.cancel();
    }

    this.wasInBackground = false;
  }

  public void startActivityTransitionTimer() {
    this.mActivityTransitionTimer = new Timer();
    this.mActivityTransitionTimerTask = new TimerTask() {
      public void run() {
        wasInBackground = true;
        System.out.println("debug Pause/Resume: --- NEED REOPENE  --");
      }
    };

    this.mActivityTransitionTimer.schedule(
      mActivityTransitionTimerTask,
      MAX_ACTIVITY_TRANSITION_TIME_MS
    );
  }
```

I need to replace NEED REOPEN log with something that makes the app reopen.
I have already tried:

```
  Intent launchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("package");
  if (launchIntent != null) {
      startActivity(launchIntent);//null pointer check in case package name was not found
  }

  Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
  intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("package","package.Activity"));
  intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
  startActivity(intent);
```

Nothing worked, I'm inside an activity

Comment: when app minimize then activity and fragment programs automatically holt, The only way to make the app working in background by `SERVICE` . In your case use `SERVICE`  to open the app again after the some time.  
It is bad practice to open the app without user intervention.  Your app might hold by Google Play store for this kind of behavior.

Comment: Interesting, thanks a lot for the tip, I'll do this test. My app is industrial and not published on the Google play store.

Comment: What strategy would you adopt for the service to identify that onPause was called?
Would monitoring a singleton variable for example work?

Comment: You could try using your launch `Intent` approach, but calling `startActivity()` on the Application `Context`, not on the `Activity `Context`.  What version of Android is your app running on?

Comment: Android 11.

        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 26

Comment: The App reopens only if another app overlaps it, if the home button is pressed the startActivity call does not work.

Comment: you can call a  method in `onPause` of `activity` or `fragment` it will call every time whenever app/activity/fragment got over relay either by popup of app or another app gets open or app gets minimize. 

you must save the current session of activity to avoid restarting the activity. can call your service from onPause by passing the name of Activity and open the same activity using service.

Comment: @WylliamBorbaBassos will share the code